# how can I pass data like the name of my user and put it in the post they created

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[image][image]so I am making an application for events and for some reason when a user creates an event the even info shows but the user info like their name and photo doesn't show up please help I've been having this problem for almost a week now.

THIS IS THE componentDidMount function

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = await getCategories();
    const categories = [{ _id: "", name: "All Categories" }, ...data];

    const { data: events } = await getEvents();
    this.setState({ events, categories });

    console.log(events);
  }
```

THIS IS THE STATE

```
class Events extends Component {
  state = {
    events: [],
    user: getUser(),
    users: getUsers(),
    showDetails: false,
    shownEventID: 0,
    showUserProfile: false,
    shownUserID: 0,
    searchQuery: ""
  };
```

THIS IS THE EVENTS FILE WHERE THE USER'S NAME AND PHOTO SHOULD BE DISPLAYED

```
<Link>
                    <img
                      className="profilePic mr-2"
                      src={"/images/" + event.hostPicture}
                      alt=""
                      onClick={() => this.handleShowUserProfile(event.userId)}
                    />
                  </Link>

                  <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}>
                    <h4
                      onClick={() => this.handleShowUserProfile(event.userId)}
                      className="host-name"
                    >
                      {getUser(event.userId).name}
                    </h4>
                  </Link>
```

This is the userService file where the getUser function is

```
import http from "./httpService";

const apiEndPoint = "http://localhost:3100/api/users";

export function register(user) {
  return http.post(apiEndPoint, {
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password,
    name: user.name
  });
}

export function getUsers() {
  return http.get(apiEndPoint);
}

export async function getUser(userId) {
  const result = await http.get(apiEndPoint + "/" + userId);
  return result.data;
}
```

This is the eventService file where the event is

```
import http from "./httpService";

const apiEndPoint = "http://localhost:3100/api/events";

export function getEvents() {
  return http.get(apiEndPoint);
}

export function getEvent(eventId) {
  return http.get(apiEndPoint + "/" + eventId);
} 

export function saveEvent(event) {
    if(event._id){
        const body = {...event}
        delete body._id
        return http.put(apiEndPoint + '/' + event._id, body)
    } 
    return http.post(apiEndPoint, event);
}

export function deleteEvent(eventId) {
  return http.delete(apiEndPoint + "/" + eventId);
}
```

Comment: Could you share the result of the `console.log(events);`?

Comment: I also added the errors I get in the console that might help

Comment: this is the the console.log(events) logs...                                                        category: {_id: "5d9b7aa6c2d4e4a246a22559", name: "Sports"}
details: "asdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklpasdfghjklp"
numOfAttendies: 20
title: "Chem Exam"
__v: 0
_id: "5d9e5e5c6ee2e2e4a180ef6b"

Comment: Good. let me see.

Comment: it is on the top of the original post all of them

Answer (score 0):

First, you have some mistakes to use the `class` in `<div>` elements.
please use `className` instead `class`.

And then second I am not sure what it is.

```
 class Events extends Component {
  state = {
    ... ...
    user: getUser(),
    ... ...
  };
```

As you seen `getUser()` function requires one parameter `userId`.
But you did not send this.
So you met internal server error to do it.
Since I did not investigate all projects, I could not provide perfectly solution.
However, it is main reason, I think.
Please check it.

Comment: I had that before and when I add userId it gives me an error saying userId is undefined

Comment: could you share your projects?

Comment: I am fairly new to coding how would I be able to share my code with you?

Comment: you could add full component on here.